# Scroll id returned by Scroll API is too long

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to use Scroll API to fetch 100K records from Kibana logs. The default size is set to 500 and I do not have authorization to change it. I tried scrolling using the below command:

```
curl -XPOST "http://elasticsearch.us-central1.gcp.cloud.internal/shared/_search?scroll=1m&size=500&pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
  "_source": ["message"],  
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "kubernetes.container_name": {
        "query": "my-container-name"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The output looks something like this:

```
{
  "scroll_id": DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNo5TkAA.... //300,000 characters long
  "took" : 16626,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 7397,
    "successful" : 7397,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
.....
```

Since the scroll id is too long, I cannot pass it on to the Scroll API to fetch the next batch of results. How can I resolve this? Is this due to large number of shards and is there any way to limit the number of shards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [discussion on ES Community](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ridiculously-long-scroll-id/12913), there seems to be a direct relation between the length of the scroll_id and the number of shards in the index.

The recommendation is to pass scroll_id in the request Body. E.g:

```
POST /_search/scroll 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ==" 
}
```

> is there any way to limit the number of shards?

1. You can to create a new index with less number of shards
2. Then Reindex the data to the new index using [ReIndex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) API
3. There is no way to reduce the number of shards of an existing index.

Comment: Can you please accept this as an answer then.

Comment: I upvoted it. How do you "accept it as an answer"?

Comment: Don't mean to come across as unhelpful but i don't see a "checkmark" to click on to mark this as the answer. Would share a screenshot in here but that doesn't appear to be an option.

Comment: @BruceMacKenzie only the person who asked the question will see that checkmark